# Handlebars.js : How to embed the view inside a partial?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

this may be a little confusing, but let me show you the problem.

I am using express-handlebars in a NodeJs web app. I have to get user input in forms. To get that done, let's say I have two separate forms in two different views 1. Login 2. Book. **What I want to achieve is code-reuse of the following partial/template:**

```
<div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
<div class="col-sm-auto">                
    <div id="form-panel" class="card" style="margin-top:15%">
        <div id="form-header" class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
                <h4>{{ formTitle }}</h4>
            </div>                    
        </div>
        <div id="form-body" class="card-body">
            {{{ formBody }}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone guide me how do I use the above template in a form like below:

```
{{> entry_form }} <!-- start of the form -->
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email_address" class="label">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email_address" id="email_address" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Email Address" autofocus required maxlength="250" value="{{email}}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" 
        required maxlength="250" value="{{password}}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" checked="{{rememberMe}}"/>
            Remeber me!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-danger">
        {{ errorMessage }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign-in" class="btn btn-success"/>
    </div>
</form> <!-- end of the form -->
```

**I want to get the following output after compilation. Assuming that {{variables}} will be replaced by the provided values in the context:**

```
<div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
<div class="col-sm-auto">                
    <div id="form-panel" class="card" style="margin-top:15%">
        <div id="form-header" class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
                <h4>Sing in</h4>
            </div>                    
        </div>
        <div id="form-body" class="card-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/login">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_address" class="label">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email_address" id="email_address" class="form-control" 
                    placeholder="Email Address" autofocus required maxlength="250" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" 
                    required maxlength="250" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" />
                        Remeber me!
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-danger">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign-in" class="btn btn-success"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. Posting here the solution just to help others if they run into such issues.

What I have done is, I have used inline partials as following.

1. enclose the login form into inline partial:

```html
{{#*inline loginForm}}
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/login">
    <!-- form contorls -->
    </form>
{{/inline}}

{{#> entry-form}}
  {{> (lookup . 'loginForm')}}
{{/entry-form}}
```

2. Define form container partial as following:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
    <div class="col-sm-auto">                
        <div id="form-panel" class="card" style="margin-top:15%">
            <div id="form-header" class="card-header">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h4>{{ formTitle }}</h4>
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div id="form-body" class="card-body">
                {{> (dataform) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that I have kept the form container partial in views/partials/entry-from.hbs file, and have loaded them by using:

```js
const express = require('express');

let app = express();

app.engine('hbs', hbs({
    extname:'hbs',
    defaultLayout:'layout',
    layoutsDir:join(__dirname,'views/layouts/'),
    partialsDir: [        
        join(__dirname,'views/partials/')
    ]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have arrived a bit late, but I would like to propose an alternative to @Nadeem Jamali's solution for those who have run into the same problem.

Reading the documentation I found the following: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-blocks

You can use `{{@partial-block}}` in order to represent the content that will be embeded into your partial. Let me give you an example:

`container-partial.hbs`

```
<h1>Welcome to the container partial!</h1>
<div style="background-color: red">
    <h2>This is the content of the partial</h2>
    {{@partial-block}}
    <!-- More code here... -->
</div>
```

Now, in every handlebars file you can use this partial like this:

`foobar.hbs`

```
{{#> container-partial }}
    <h1>And here you can write the content of "container-partial", in other words, what is going to be replaced in @partial-block</h1>
{{/container-partial}}
```

And the output after compilation will be:

```
<h1>Welcome to the container partial!</h1>
<div style="background-color: red">
    <h2>This is the content of the partial</h2>
    <h1>And here you can write the content of "container-partial", in other words, what is going to be replaced in @partial-block</h1>
    <!-- More code here... -->
</div>
```

In this case, we can find a solution to [@nadeem-jamali's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510739/handlebars-js-how-to-embed-the-view-inside-a-partial) by doing the following:

`form-container.hbs`

```
<div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
    <div class="col-sm-auto">                
        <div id="form-panel" class="card" style="margin-top:15%">
            <div id="form-header" class="card-header">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h4>{{ formTitle }}</h4>
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div id="form-body" class="card-body">
                {{> @partial-block }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, we can use the partial like this:

`login-form.hbs`

```
{{#> form-container formTitle="FooBar"}}
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/login">
    <!-- Form content -->
  </form>
{{/form-container}}
```

And the result will be:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
    <div class="col-sm-auto">                
        <div id="form-panel" class="card" style="margin-top:15%">
            <div id="form-header" class="card-header">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h4>FooBar</h4>
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div id="form-body" class="card-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/login">
                <!-- Form content -->
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :D !